# How to multiply row by column in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

There is a resulting matrix `matrix = np.array(...)` and I would like to multiply `i` row by `j` column. How can I implement this?

Comment: `m[i] * m[:, j]` assuming shapes are aligned.  Can you show your attempt/data?

Comment: @user3483203 after multiplication, what data type should the result have? in my case, a one-dimensional array came out, although it should have got one number

Comment: @RoyalGoose You should definitely provide a sample data, expected output, also what you have tried so far. The question as of now is not clear and could be closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question is ill-defined because it has more than one interpretation:

- Element-wise product
  `m[i] * m[:, j]` which is a vector.
- OP wants a different meaning, I guess it's a [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product): `np.dot(m[i], m[:, j])` or `np.sum(m[i] * m[:, j])`

Answer (score 0):

just a simple multiply will do the work for you.

```
row = matrix[i]
column = matrix[:,j]
result = sum(row*column)
```

Comment: what type of data `result`? in my case, a one-dimensional array came out, although it should have got one number

Comment: Then you need to do a sum on the result, I thought you are interested only in the multiplication. I have edited the response to reflect the sum.